# Get New Window Decorations Stuck On Initializing

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am using Kubuntu 14.04 at this time and I have problem with getting new window decorations.

When I click get new window decorations, it took forever on initializing. Also the same at Desktop Effects, but not in Desktop Theme.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same exact problem. As a work around for window decorations you can do the following.

Download an Aurorae theme from www.kde-look.org.
Extract the theme and copy the resulting folder to ~/.kde/share/apps/aurorae/themes

Open Window Decorations in System Settings, you should now see your new theme listed.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching and updating package **GHNS** and comment back if this works.

GHNS=Get Hot New Stuff

*Note*: some outdated packages will be removed upon update of this package.